# Annotating splice junctions from tophat/STAR output

Tags: rna-seq

Is there a way to annotate the splice junctions output from tophat/STAR output?

What I mean by annotate is can I know if it was involved in an alternative splicing event say skipped exon, MXE or retained intron...?

I did some research looks like rMATS does it but we do not have access to the data all we have is output from tophat(.bed file) and STAR(SJ.out) files

Data available:
Splice junction files from star and tophat2 for some reason they deleted the bams in the same directory (from what i know they purged all files with size greater than something)

Species: human aligned to GRCh37(ensembl).

Goal :

Annotate splice junctions based on event it is involved an event skipped exon, MXE or A3ss or A5ss.

I did some more research and saw that ucsc table browser has UCSC Alt events as an option the data looks like this

```
#bin    chrom   chromStart  chromEnd    name    score   strand
0   chr1    67108547    67109226    atacIntron  0   +
22  chr1    111148925   111149075   altPromoter 0   -
35  chr1    220046661   220292759   strangeSplice   0   +
73  chr1    917423  917573  altPromoter 0   -
75  chr1    2489907 2491261 retainedIntron  0   +
93  chr1    21494532    21496156    strangeSplice   0   -
95  chr1    23720526    23724037    atacIntron  0   -
100 chr1    28835417    28837404    bleedingExon    0   +
153 chr1    84259617    84379035    strangeSplice   0   -
```

Not sure how they curate this.